# How to create txt file in source package folder sub folder ( source package -> invoice)

Tags: java, netbeans, file-handling, netbeans-8

[image]

[image]

I need to create a `.txt` file in the invoices folder. I am using Windows 10. How can I do that? I've tried:

```
File myObj = new File("\\invoice\\filename.txt");
```

and

```
File myObj = new File("/invoice/filename.txt");
```

But it did not work. Thank you for your support.

Comment: java program does not run in source folder! In the IDE it runs in a bin foler, BTW you have added an absolue path. which means you should fine an invoice folder in the root of your C drive

Comment: Thanks i figured out Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jens said do not use a project source folder to write the file.
At run-time of the standalone application there might not be a folder `invoice`,
and also you might risk compiling a garbage file into the application jar.

The user's home directory is `System.getProperty("user.home")` and work from there on. That is the appropriate directory tree for user specific files.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I did not add the following lines:

```
objFile.createNewFile();
System.getProperty("user.dir")
```